# Can you search for tags in OneNote for Mac 2016?

Tags: ms-office, microsoft, onenote

Searching for tagged content within a notebook in OneNote for Windows is straightforward. There's a **Find Tags** menu option.

[image: Find tags in OneNote for Windows]

This option does not seem to exist in OneNote for Mac 2016. There's nothing to the right of **To Do Tag**. Therefore, you can't search your notebook for "discuss with manager", for instance.

[image: Tag example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is not (yet) available in OneNote for Mac.

Since I also use Visio and Project, I have a Windows VM with OneNote also installed.  From there, I use the "Find Tag" feature and create a new page with the To-Do tags and then allow it to sync to my Mac and iPhone.

It's **very** cludgy, but for now, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I am subscribed to be an early user/tester of early release versions. The version I have on mac allows you to search tags in the same area you would search for words. It allows you to search pages or search Tags. Finally!!